# Form NSPredicate from string that contains id's

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have this problem where I can't think of how to write this predicate.

I have an Entity called Contact, it has a string property "pages", let's say

```
contact.pages = @"1,5,11,15,17";
```

There is a lot of contacts in my database, and I want to fetch only these contacts that contains a certain id. So let's say I want to fetch only these contacts, which pages contains id @"1".

I can think of something like this,

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.pages CONTAINS %@", _pageId];
```

But my problem is that this would also get contacts, that e.g has pages = @"11,15".

So any ideas on how to achieve that?
I would be grateful for any suggestions, thanks in advance!

Comment: actualy this string is formed like this, i have an array of id and i join that with:
[idArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]; so if my id is in the last place, this wouldn't work, yes?
EDIT: or if this string has only one object, it wouldn't work also

Comment: can you use the values of the array and filter by ids not by pages?

Comment: well i don't really know, these so called pages ar really ids of other coreData entities. I have also an entity called page. And these contacs belong to multiple pages. The list to which pages this contact belongs goes as a comma seperated string.
I have a way of achieving this, by going through all the contacts, and seperating this string into an array, but this takes very long, and i want to achieve this by using a predicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "MATCHES" operator of `NSPredicate` can be used to compare against a regular expression:

```
NSString *pageId = @"1";
NSString *regex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(.*,)?%@(,.*)?", pageId];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pages MATCHES %@", regex];
```

But you should also consider to replace the string property by a to-many relationship to a *Page* entity, then the predicate would look like

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY pages.pageid == %@", pageId];
```