# How do I create a core data entry with a queryable array property?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two entities, `Issue` and `User`, which I'm using to represent data that comes to me from a server.  There's a many-to-many relationship between Issues and Users, and when I get an Issue from the server the object has an array of User IDs.

Later, when I get a User from the server, I want to be able to find the issues that I've stored that have a matching ID.

I had been planning to use a transformable property to store the User IDs for each Issue.  However, I've read that transformable properties aren't queryable.  Is that true?  If so, how do I create an array property that is queryable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct that you cannot query for entries in an array that is stored as a transformable attribute of the entity.

One possible solution would be to store the list of users IDs as a comma-separated string attribute in the `Issue` entity, and later search for a matching ID as described here:
[Form NSPredicate from string that contains id's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932595/form-nspredicate-from-string-that-contains-ids).

A different solution would be to create the relationships from `Issue` to `User` already in the first pass, when reading and creating the issues. When you get an issue from the server with a list of user IDs, you would find or create the `User` objects and set the relationship.

Comment: The second approach would be nice, but I don't have the User objects at that point.  I'll try the string serialisation approach, though - thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Simon: The idea with the second approach is that you just create User objects in the first pass (and perhaps set only the userID attribute). In the second pass you can update the (already existing) User objects with the full information, or create more User objects if they don't exist already.

Comment: Even if you have many user objects they will be in memory(the full objects with the iVars initialized) only when you create and set the relationship. Otherwise they will be loaded into memory only when any individual property of it is accessed.

Comment: No, what I mean is that we have so many users it's not practical to load them all from the server.  The app would be sat there for minutes waiting to load all the users before it was ready to load the Issue.

Comment: @Simon: The idea of the second approach is not to create all users beforehand. For example, if you read an Issue with user ids 2,5,9 from the server, then you create 3 User objects and set the relationship from the Issue to these 3 Users. Then you read an Issue with user ids 1, 5, 10. The User object for id 5 exists already, so you have to create 2 User objects for ids 1 and 10, and so on. Each time you read an Issue from the server, you "find or create" the User objects for this issue, and set the relationships.

Comment: Exactly. You just create placeholder users for only the id's related to the issue.

Comment: @Rakesh: Thank you, "placeholder" is a good description for what I tried to say!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using two entities with many-to-many relationship why don't you implement the relationship using core-data? i.e The `usersSet` (say) in `Issue` entity will be an `NSSet` and the `issuesSet` in `User` will be also an `NSSet`. If thats the case you could implement a predicate in the below way to easily get what you want:

(The below code assumes the to-many relationship between `Issue` to `User` is `usersSet`.)

```
User *userObjFromServer = <your user object from server>... 
NSString *userId = userObjFromServer.userId; //Whichever way you are doing this
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY usersSet.userId like %@",userId];
```

The queryable array you are talking about will be the relationship (only, its an `NSSet`).

Comment: Just noticed the answer by @Martin goes along the same line. The take away would be the predicate. And you don't have to worry about having so many User objects . Faulting in core-data will help you keep the memory-footprint as low as possible (i.e if you are following the second approach in his answer).

Comment: As I've mentioned to Martin, the problem is that there are so many users that it's not practical to load them from the server in advance.