# NSPredicate to use with Transformable property

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have array of strings which I save in Core Data as Transformable. From json I am gettings needed strings like this:

```
if let mealTimes = dictionary["mealTimes"] as? [String]{
     self.mealTimes = mealTimes
}
```

Now I would like to filter fetch results by strings in mealTime property. I have tried this way:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mealTimes LIKE[cd] '*%@*'", "breakfast")
var breakfastContents = StaticContent.fetchStaticContentsWithPredicate(predicate, inManagedObjectContext: self.coreDataStack.context)
if (breakfastContents.count > 0) {
    breakfast = breakfastContents.first!
}
```

The problem is that result array is empty but I know I have breakfast string in some content. So how can I fix it? I was reading something about saving transformable as NSData so it would need some great trick. I was trying to use `LIKE` (with and without *) command and `CONTAINS`.

Extension for StaticContent:

```
class func fetchStaticContentsWithPredicate(predicate: NSPredicate, inManagedObjectContext managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [StaticContent] {

    // Define fetch request/predicate
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "StaticContent")

    // Assign fetch request properties
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]


    // Handle results
    let fetchedResults = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [StaticContent]
    return fetchedResults
}
```

Comment: You *can't* use a predicate to filter the content of a transformable property, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337808/how-do-i-create-a-core-data-entry-with-a-queryable-array-property.

Answer (score -3):

You should refactor your data model to get rid of the "array of strings". This is not a very sound way to store this type of values.

Instead, consider a relationship with a new entity that captures those strings. Alternatively, device a scheme where you store a string and have a unique character that separates the records (e.g `;` or something similar). Then any simple string predicate would work, like this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "mealtimes contains[cd] %@", "breakfast")
```