# How to filter NSPredicate for inclusion in Swift?

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I need to filter using `IN`. Here is my code:

```
let choices = "1,2,3,4"
```

Then use it like this, which crashes the app:

```
NSPredicate(format: "id in %@", @choices)
```

I've also tried:

```
NSPredicate(format: "id in [1,2,3,4]")
```

But get this error:

```
'Unable to parse the format string "id in [1,2,3,4]"'
```

Comment: `"1,2,3,4"` Really? `@choices`? Really? Really??

Comment: If you really have to store the list as a comma-separated string then this might help: [Form NSPredicate from string that contains id's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932595/form-nspredicate-from-string-that-contains-ids).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let choices = "1,2,3,4"` - it is a string, must be an array `let choices = [1,2,3,4]`

if `id` is the Property which you want to compare -

`NSPredicate(format: "id in %@", @choices)` replace `@choices` with `choices`

Result - `NSPredicate(format: "id in %@", choices)`

If you want to compare the object itself
`NSPredicate(format: "self in %@", @choices)` replace `@choices` with `choices`, and `id` with `self`

Result - `NSPredicate(format: "self in %@", choices)`
self is (points to) the object which is compared/evaluated for given predicate.

Comment: This is being used in CoreData. id is an attribute on this entity.

Comment: While the above probably works, it doesn't have to be an array.  This works fine:  NSPredicate(format: "id in {\(choices)}").

Comment: @4thSpace That needs a \ before the first parenthesis in order to escape it and recognize it as a variable: `NSPredicate(format: "id in {\(choices)}")`

Answer (score 1):

choices needs to be surrounded by braces `{` and `}`.  Then it will work.

```
NSPredicate(format: "id in {\(choices)}")
```

The resulting string looks like:

```
id in {1,2,3,4}
```

Comment: And if `choices` contains any special characters (like quotation marks) then it will crash. String interpolation in format strings is a bad idea.

Comment: It's controlled so there is no risk of any other format appearing.