# Fetch from core data where value contains string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have a core data table called **Forms** which contains a attribute called **objectids** which holds a comma separated string with ids. (it can also contain just one id)
ex.

```
objectids = "90"          // one id
objectids = "91,23,44"    // multiple ids
```

I receive a **objectid** and I want to match that and see if it exists as a value in any **Forms** -> **objectids** entry.

What is important is that it only matches whole string. ie. **objectid**: **1** should not match with **objectids**: **91, 23, 44**, etc.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
-(NSDictionary*)readForm:(NSString*)objectid
{

  ...

  NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Forms"];
  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"added_date" ascending:NO];
  [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
  [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
  fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userid == %@ AND objectids == %@ AND active == %@", user.userid, objectid, @"yes"];

  // *** in this fetchRequest I want to include some snippet of code to:
  // *** Match string, but only whole string seperated by commas, unless it only has one value in which case it contains no commas.

  NSError *err = nil;
  NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err];
  if([results count])
  {    
    ...
  }
}
```

I hope it's understandable.

I simply do not know enough of objective C to even know what terms to search for.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To clarify, do you want to match "22,1,5"as well when looking for "1", or only "1"? I. E. Do you want to find a single item in a list in an entry, but not partially match items? Or is this list more like an IP address, where you only want to match the entire list?

Comment: Yes sorry, If the objectids = "22,1,5" I want "1" to match, (also match "22" or "5")

Comment: What are the objectids?  If they relate to other objects in your CoreData store, then it sounds like you need to consider a to-many relationship, rather than using a single string attribute to hold multiple references.

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain, as there is a whole backend to this. But they do not relate to other core data. All they are for is to check if the value I receive in this function exists in objectids. They are not "smart" in any other way.

Comment: @A.Daleby in that case, a variation on ChiellieNL's answer below should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For string comparisons, you could use LIKE instead of ==, and also, for your bool, use a literal, @YES, so your predicate would be :

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userid == %@ AND objectids LIKE %@ AND active == %@", user.userid, objectid, @YES];
```

For more complex string comparisons, you could use a predicateWithBlock:

EDIT : reading your further comments, I think this question answers the exact same problem using regex : [Form NSPredicate from string that contains id's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932595/form-nspredicate-from-string-that-contains-ids)

Comment: I followed the link you provided. Using regex worked.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your example:

```
objectids = "90"          // one id
objectids = "91,23,44"    // multiple ids
```

In case there's only 1 id, you can compare the full string. In case there are more ids, they are always either preceded or followed by a comma.

Perhaps you can use something like this:

```
NSString *first = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%%", objectid];
NSString *last = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%,%@", objectid];
NSString *inBetween = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%,%@,%%", objectid];

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userid == %@ AND (objectids == %@ OR objectids LIKE %@ OR objectids LIKE %@ OR objectids LIKE %@) AND active == %@", user.userid, objectid, first, last, inBetween, @"yes"];
```

Which should make a statement like:

- objectids IS exactly "90"   OR
- objectids starts with "90,"   OR
- objectids ends with ",90"  OR
- objectids contains ",90,"